# If GROUP BY is absent, are all the tuples treated as one group or is every tuple treated as a group?

Tags: sql

In Silberschatz's Database System Concepts:

> Tuples satisfying the where predicate are then placed into groups by the group by clause if it is present. If the group by clause is absent, the entire set of tuples satisfying the where predicate is treated as being in one group.

If GROUP BY is absent, in what sense are all the tuples satisfying WHERE treated as one group?

I thought each tuple satisfying WHERE is treated as a group, because ORDER BY orders the groups when GROUP BY is present, and orders all the tuples when GROUP BY is absent.

Comment: Absent `group by` and when there are no rows meeting the filters, there is still a row created to return the aggregates.

Comment: Aggregation occurr explicitly when there is a use of GROUP BY clause *or* implicitly when there is a use of aggregation function. In the later case, all tuples/rows are part of a single group. In both cases, a group is being represented by by a single tuple/row. Simple example: explicit: group the  people in the room by the color of their shirt and count how many are in each group. Implicit: count the people in the room.

Answer (score 1):

This explanation is related to aggregate functions, not to `ORDER BY`.

When you have a `GROUP BY` aggregate functions, such as `COUNT` and `MAX`, are computed for each group of tuples. When there is no `GROUP BY`, these functions are applied to all tuples passing `WHERE`, in effect treating them as a single group.

Comment: Thanks. Without group by, when are all tuples treated as one group, and when each tuple as a group?

Comment: @Tim I can't think of a situation when each tuple is treated as a group in the absence of a `GROUP BY`.